# How to remove emacs keybindings from Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts

At some point in the past I installed emacs keybindings into my jupyter notebook using the following package: https://github.com/rmcgibbo/jupyter-emacskeys

I am trying to remove them as the keybindings don't work as well for me in the notebook as they do in emacs and I'd prefer the default keybindings back.

I tried uninstalling the keybindings with

`pip uninstall jupyter-emacskeys`

while it did uninstall the package the keybinds remained. I tried reinstalling jupyter by running

`pip uninstall jupyter`
`pip install jupyter`

but once again the keybinds remain, how can I restore the default keybindings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open file `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`, your `load_extensions` value is some thing like this:

  `"load_extensions": {
    "jupyter_emacskeys/init": true
  }`

just delete it and restart kernel.